# Appmaker: Opening a page where the record is pre-selected

Tags: google-app-maker

first-time questioner here!

- I have a page called Dashboard and it has a table listing all Products.
- On each Product table row there is a button
- I want to click the edit button to open a new page called 'Products' where instead of it showing all products, it shows only the selected record.

Solutions I can think of (but don't know which is best or how to properly implement)
- create a filtered query datasource with a parameter
- write a function and call it from the onClick event (I cannot write JS)
- write some simple code in the custom action of the onclick event

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loK9t.jpg)

(I'm a citizen coder - my background was MS Access where you could write things like (Open X page where ID=current.record). I am learning slowly by working through the examples but I am not finding there is much documentation from Google so sorry for the basic question.

Comment: If your datasource on your 'Products' page is the same as your Product table datasource then this should automatically select your record that you clicked the 'edit' button on. Your edit button should just have the page navigate to your page. Ideally your Products page just needs to have an edit form.

Comment: Hi thanks - i should have said - this is not a Popup or a Dialogue -. This is navigating to a completely new page. FWIW - both pages have the same datasource but i dont know how to parse that record 'key'

Comment: Is your table the built in App Maker table widget, or did you build your own HTML table? If you are using the table widget, when you click your edit button it will select the item associated with that table row, and if your detail page is set to the same datasource with an edit form or a reference to datasource.item, then that page should be displaying all details for the selected table row. The only other thing you could try in your edit button click is widget.datasource.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key) and then navigate to your page. But this really should not make any difference.

Comment: thanks - let me try this when i get back to office and i will report back - thanks for helping

Comment: thanks - i have got it working - the problem was the new page was not linked to the identical datasource. thanks so much for your help - it got me thinking about the problem in a different way.